# Matlab how define an integral function and find best coefficients

Tags: matlab, integral, best-fit-curve

I would like to find coefficients to best fit the nonlinear functions, and the nonlinear functions was an integral function. So the first step was to define an function:

```
function dT = km(x,sT)

fun=@(temp)((-x(1)*x(2)*(temp).^(x(2)-1.0))./ ...  
                ((x(3)^x(2))*((1+(temp./x(3)).^x(2)).^2)));
dT=integral(fun,0,sT);
% x is a array containing three coefficients;
% sT is a array containing integral upper limits;
$ dT is integral values;
```

And then the `lsqcurvefit` function was called to find best coefficients:

```
 x0=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]; % initial coefficients;
 x1=[300.0 -10.0 0.0]; % lower limit;
 x2=[500.0 0.0 1000.0]; % upper limit;

stimeT=[1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0]; %  XDATA
dmT=[3.0 6.0 9.0 12.0 15.0 18.0 21.0 24.0]; % YDATA

    [x,resnorm]=lsqcurvefit(@km,x0,stimeT,dmT,x1,x2);
```

But I got these errors:

```
Error using integral (line 86)
A and B must be floating point scalars.
Error in km (line 6)
dT=integral(fun,0.0,sT);
Error in lsqcurvefit (line 195)
            initVals.F = feval(funfcn_x_xdata{3},xCurrent,XDATA,varargin{:});
Error in individual_kernel (line 57)
 [x,resnorm]=lsqcurvefit(@km,x0,stimeT,dmT,x1,x2);
Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. LSQCURVEFIT
    cannot continue.
```

MATLAB's default data type is double, and double is a type of floating, so I do not know how to modify the code.
Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `integral` function requires its second and third arguments to be scalars. If you want to build the array `dT` of integrals over the limits contained in the array `sT` (or `silkingT`—your reported error is not consistent with the provided code), use in the definition of function `km`:

```
dT = arrayfun(@(T) integral(fun,0,T), sT);
```